# gdal2tiles.py performance is >2X slower on Ubuntu small than Ubuntu full

Tags: gdal, gdal-python-bindings, gdal2tiles.py

I can't tell why yet but for some reason, when I tile an image using gdal2tiles.py it is much slower on an Ubuntu small. I have been using an ortho image from my project that is 68MB in size and here are the timings I get using this command `time gdal2tiles.py -w none /code/data/239633.tif /tmp/tiles`:

ghcr.io/osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-3.6.3

```
Generating Base Tiles:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100
Generating Overview Tiles:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100

real    0m46.449s
user    0m27.440s
sys     0m19.001s
```

ghcr.io/osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-full-3.6.3

```
Generating Base Tiles:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100
Generating Overview Tiles:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100

real    0m19.626s
user    0m19.488s
sys     0m0.130s
```